# Laravel 5.8 Font Awesome showing as a square instead of the icon

Tags: laravel, npm, sass, font-awesome-5

I am trying to get the icon showing up however within my project whenever I use Font Awesome it is displaying as a square.

I am using npm packet management.

This is what I have in my app.scss file:

```
// Variables
@import 'variables';

// Fontawesome
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid.scss';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands.scss';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular.scss';
```

Inside the _variables.scss file I have this:

```
// Font Awesome
$fa-font-path: "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts";
```

This is what I have in the package.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.12.0",
    "axios": "^0.19",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2",
    "laravel-mix": "^4.0.7",
    "lodash": "^4.17.13",
    "material-design-iconic-font": "^2.2.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.12",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
    "sass": "^1.15.2",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "sweetalert": "^2.1.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by adding the below in the webpack.mix.js

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

mix.setPublicPath('public');
mix.setResourceRoot('../');
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be a number of things.  Top contenders (that have stopped me in the past) are:

1) Make sure you haven't overridden the `font-family` on the page with some kind of wildcard for example:

`* { font-family: // etc`

2) Easy mistake - remember that Font Awesome 5 has depreciated the `fa` syntax and moved to `fas` or `fab`.  This one got me to the point where I just stayed with V4 as all our projects would have needed refactoring.

3) Triple check that your path to FA files is correct and that it is translating correctly within your site (IE to the right folder from the server)

4) I am not familiar with the tilda for the imports.  This usually works for me:

```
npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

Then in your scss file:

```
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss';
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the same problem was, because I added accidentally this code

```
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/fontawesome';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/regular';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/solid';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/brands';
```

to `app.css` instead of `app.scss`